# Logout.php does not destroy cookie or login

Tags: php, mysql

**I have a logout.php link, which if the user clicks it is supposed to log them out.**

```
<?php
    // logout.php
    // you must start session before destroying it
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    //}
    //echo "You have been successfully logged out.
?>
```

**However, when I return back to the login.php - it automatically redirects them to the landing page after login.php.
Below is the code for login.php**

```
<?php 

     // Connects to your Database 

     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die( mysql_error() ); 
     mysql_select_db("sales") or die( mysql_error() );

    //Checks if there is a login cookie

    if( isset( $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'] ) ) {

        //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page 
        $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
        $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];

         $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die( mysql_error() );
         while( $info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ) ) {
            if ( $pass != $info['password'] ) {
            } else {
              header("Location: sales.php");
            }
         }
     }

     // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
     $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
     $hour = time() + 3600; 
     setcookie( ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour ); 
     setcookie( Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour );    

     //then redirect them to the members area 

     header("Location: sales.php");
```

Comment: use `unset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']);` and `unset($_COOKIE['Key_my_site']);`. It should work. Also use $_SESSION .... it's much better than $_COOKIE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// logout.php
// you must start session before destroying it
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
//}
//echo "You have been successfully logged out.
///to unet the cookie set it to a pas t time
setcookie ("ID_my_site", "", time() - 3600);

?>
```

Comment: @bnovation Please accept and vote up this answer if it helps you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are sessions are not the same thing (though the latter is often backed by an identifier stored in a cookie).

Storing username and password in a cookie is a terrible idea. Use `$_SESSION` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`cookies` and `session` are different.  Cookies are stored in client's browsers whereas sessions are stored in the server which is probably what you want to use for storing `username` and `pass` (in your case).

If you switched to using session then your `logout.php` should work just fine, however if you wish to continue using cookies you should use the following in your `logout.php`:

```
setcookie('ID_my_site', ''); 
setcookie('Key_my_site', '');
```